# Google Cloud Shell won't start; throws usage limits exceeded msg

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

This is a **Google Cloud Storage** service related question; specifically about **Google Cloud Shell** and inability to start it. It worked fine for the past week. But today, about 3 hours earlier onward, when I visit:

> https://console.cloud.google.com/storage

...and click on **Products & Services** (the side-drawer menu, top left corner), and then choose **Storage** (under STORAGE services), and then click on **Activate Google Cloud Shell**, it says:

> Connecting: Provisioning your Google Cloud Shell machine...

...and then the following message:

> Service usage limits temporarily exceeded. Try connecting later. If
>   you believe this is an error, please **report via feedback**. **Close**

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R5z2.jpg)

The message clearly says limits exceeded... But all I've been doing is:

```
gsutil -lhr gs://some-bucket/my-dir/** | tail -10
```

and

```
watch -n 25 'gsutil -lhr gs://some-bucket/my-dir/** | tail -10'
```

I let the `watch` command running (BTW: does this operation incur a cost?).

I am **uploading about 205 GBs of podcast archives (MP3s)** that I need to hold onto for my research. So far I've transferred 89.9 GBs of data using:

```
gsutil -m cp -r my-dir gs://some-bucket
```

...from my laptop (sadly, Win 10 Pro for the moment). I don't have access to a Linux box to get a *simple, clean listing with human-readable file sizes and summary, the last few lines, `tail -10` i.e. (to keep an eye on progress of uploads, nor does `gsutil cp` provide any).*

Trying to do the same on my Windows laptop involves some trashy PowerShell BS which I have no inclination in spending time on! :(

But now I **can't start a Google Cloud Shell**, which indeed was a great convenience...

I checked billing and see this:

> **Cloud Storage Durable Reduced Availability Storage:** 2.541
>   Gibibyte-months (Source:some-bucket), US$ 0.05 debited

and

> **Cloud Storage Class A Request:** 13998 Counts (Source:some-bucket), US$
>   0.14 debited.

That's fine with me, as I am OK to pay for the storage I use and the operations I make.

Any tips on why cloud shell access won't start and give that limit-exceeded message?

Comment: You should use the feedback link in the message to report this.  There are [limits](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits) Cloud Shell has on resources like CPU and network, you are likely hitting one of those.  The feedback report will help to look into this.

P.S. I work for Google.

Comment: Thanks, Alexey. I did that before I posted here (highlighted the message too... :)

Comment: @AlexeyAlexandrov I'm running into this problem as well, but when I click on the "please report via feedback" link, nothing happens. The "Service usage limit" works fine. I tried Firefox, Chrome, Safari and all did the same, so I cannot report anything. Any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been resolved for me by Google; I had Cloud Shell sessions open for prolonged periods of time and had exceeded some fair-use limits set for it.

Anyone facing a lockout like this, please be sure to provide feedback as suggested by [Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848626/alexey-alexandrov) above.

Thanks once again, Alexey, for resetting the counters and re-enabling the console access...

Comment: You can also open a ticket if you have support to speed along this process. It took them 4 days to extend the usage quota limits from 40 hours to 100 hours weekly for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue, the shell takes forever and stuck there. 
I simply clicked **'+' (open a new tab)**.

A few seconds later, problems solved!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with with firefox where it hangs with 'Provisioning your Google Cloud Shell machine...'

Switched to google chrome and it got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're in urgent situation. There are 2 options for you:

1. Set up Google Cloud SDK on your computer and use your terminal/shell of your computer to work.
2. Switch to Ephemeral Mode. Please notice that it is a fresh env and does not maintain any persistent state between sessions.

[image]